# FedEx Rates/Transit API multi box shipment - show individual rates per box

Tags: fedex

I am using the Rates and Transit time API in the FedEx developer portal.
I am sending a multiple box shipment to get the rate.  However, it gives me the total price, but not the individual price per box.

There is a a specific setting that is document clearly that gives the choice between showing the complete bundled rate, or the individual package rate (the one I want).  However, it doesn't work.
This is the specific part that show control it.

```
"variableHandlingChargeDetail": {
  "rateType": "ACCOUNT",
  "rateLevelType": "INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGE_RATE",
}
```

Whats interesting here is if I only query 1 package, then I get one-element array that that shows individual packages (only 1), with or without the setting above.
But as soon as I add another package, that array isn't in the response at all.

Anybody know how to do this?
This a link to the docs: https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-us/catalog/rate/v1/docs.html

Keep in mind, this is for their newer API, not the older SOAP/XML one.

I tried using the specific setting outlined in the docs, and I expected individual package rates, however, I just got the combined rate.